# My laptop is supposed to support 16GB of RAM, but only 8GB is reported (but the chips and slots all work)

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, hardware-detection

Here's the scenario.  I got [this laptop, a Clevo W230SS](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Clevo-W230SS-Schenker-XMG-P304-Barebones-Notebook.113676.0.html) recently.  I also bought [two of these](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148733) 8GB RAM sticks.  However; **my laptop will only detect 8GB of RAM**.  More specifically:

- Both RAM sticks work just fine.
- Both slots also work.
- Both the BIOS (Prema Mod, version 1.03.03PM v1) and the operating system (Ubuntu 16.04, stock kernel) report 8GB available.
- The RAM sticks are firmly inserted.
- I can provide more detailed information or photos if necessary.

Any tips?

Comment: So how did you check that both sticks and both slots work fine? If you unplug wither of them the laptop still reports 8 gb of RAM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, crap.  Turns out some part of the laptop (likely the CPU, I'm told) doesn't like having two 1866Mhz RAM sticks; so I just used two 1600Mhz sticks I had lying around.  Works like a charm, all 16GB are ready for use.

Comment: Next time buy something like Dell, HP, Lenovo, or Sony. Fujitsu also has a comprehensive burn-in technology, so do Acer and Samsung.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Because I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Operating DRAM at it's maximum frequency requires quality PCB routing, especially for full load in dual memory configuration. Apparently the design of your particular laptop is not up to other designs.

Comment: How can I tell what frequency my RAM is being run at?

Comment: You run this utility, http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: Err, sorry, on Linux?

Comment: If you are so sophisticated user and employ Linux-based OS, don't you know how to use Google? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2038338